# Example setup for using arquillian with Websphere Liberty Profile 8.5.5.4

Tags: jboss-arquillian, websphere-liberty

I was not able to get an Arquillian testcase running together with WLP 8.5.5.4. Is there any simple example project in place which demonstrates this to me? I did not find one.

Answer (score 2):

You can find complex setup with creation of testing server in this redbook [Configuring and Deploying Open Source with WebSphere Application Server Liberty Profile](http://www.redbooks.ibm.com/redpieces/abstracts/sg248194.html).

Here you have very basic setup:

- Configure `arquillian.xml` file for WebSphere Liberty:

  ```
  <arquillian xmlns="http://jboss.org/schema/arquillian" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
      xsi:schemaLocation="http://jboss.org/schema/arquillian http://jboss.org/schema/arquillian/arquillian_1_0.xsd">

  <engine>
      <property name="deploymentExportPath">target/</property>
  </engine>

  <container qualifier="wlp-managed-85" default="true">
      <configuration>
          <property name="wlpHome">C:/IBM/WebSphere/wlp</property>
          <property name="serverName">defaultServer</property>
          <property name="httpPort">9080</property>
          <property name="appDeployTimeout">20</property>
          <property name="appUndeployTimeout">20</property>
      </configuration>
  </container>
  ```
- Configure required dependencies in the `pom.xml`:

  ```
  <!-- Configure WASdev repository -->
  <repositories>
      <repository>
          <releases>
              <updatePolicy>never</updatePolicy>
          </releases>
          <snapshots>
              <enabled>false</enabled>
              <updatePolicy>never</updatePolicy>
          </snapshots>
          <id>ibm-maven-repo</id>
          <name>ibm-maven-repo</name>
          <url>http://public.dhe.ibm.com/ibmdl/export/pub/software/websphere/wasdev/maven/repository/</url>
      </repository>
  </repositories>
  <pluginRepositories>
      <pluginRepository>
          <id>ibm-maven-repo</id>
          <name>ibm-maven-repo</name>
          <url>http://public.dhe.ibm.com/ibmdl/export/pub/software/websphere/wasdev/maven/repository/</url>
          <layout>default</layout>
          <snapshots>
              <enabled>true</enabled>
          </snapshots>
          <releases>
              <enabled>true</enabled>
          </releases>
      </pluginRepository>
  </pluginRepositories>

  <dependencyManagement>
  <dependencies>
      <dependency>
          <groupId>org.jboss.arquillian</groupId>
          <artifactId>arquillian-bom</artifactId>
          <version>1.1.8.Final</version>
          <scope>import</scope>
          <type>pom</type>
      </dependency>
  </dependencies>
  ```

  .....

  ```
  <dependency>
      <groupId>com.ibm.tools.target</groupId>
      <artifactId>was-liberty</artifactId>
      <version>LATEST</version>
      <type>pom</type>
      <scope>provided</scope>
  </dependency>
  <dependency>
      <groupId>junit</groupId>
      <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
      <version>4.11</version>
      <scope>test</scope>
  </dependency>
  <dependency>
      <groupId>org.jboss.arquillian.junit</groupId>
      <artifactId>arquillian-junit-container</artifactId>
      <scope>test</scope>
  </dependency>
  <dependency>
      <!-- Arquillian WebSphere Liberty Profile support -->
      <groupId>org.jboss.arquillian.container</groupId>
      <artifactId>arquillian-wlp-managed-8.5</artifactId>
      <version>1.0.0.Alpha2</version>
      <scope>test</scope>
  </dependency>
  ```